# Rails, has_and_belongs_to_many, :HashWithIndifferentAccess error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client-server, activeresource, has-and-belongs-to-many

On my server, I have two models:

**Broadcast**

```
class Broadcast < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :content

  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :feeds

  attr_accessible :content, :feeds, :feeds_attributes

end
```

**Feed**

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :broadcasts
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

On my client, I have basic ActiveResource classes for those models.

When I try to create new Broadcast with given Feeds (from client):

```
feed = Feed.find(3) <-succesful

broadcast = Broadcast.new
broadcast.attributes['feed'] ||= [] 
broadcast.feed << feed
broadcast.save
```

In BroadcastController on the server, I simply do

```
@broadcast = Broadcast.new(params[:broadcast])
```

it gives following error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Feed(#45931224) expected, got
>   ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#25685616)):

I tried changing

```
broadcast.attributes['feed'] ||= []
```

to

```
broadcast.attributes['feed_attributes'] ||= []
```

But it gave me “Unknown attribute error”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, I was missing:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :feeds
```

in my Broadcast method.

Anyway, should anyone encounter this question, please note that:

```
broadcast.attributes['feed_attributes'] ||= []
```

is correct, without '_attributes' suffix the HashWithIndifferentAccess error still occurs.